# Spring MVC Updating to 4.3.5.RELEASE, Imports cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I started experimenting with the Spring MVC framework, following some tutorials.
AFAIK the 4.3.5.RELEASE is the current release version, but when changing the version in my pom.xml, some of my imports (e.g. org.springframework.stereotype.Controller) cannot be resolved anymore.

I could not find any causes for this, any ideas? Version 4.3.4.RELEASE is working...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.blub.blib</groupId>
<artifactId>blub-mvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

<springframework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
</properties>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are including all the dependencies? It seems to be working for me.

Comment: Is this in an IDE? Does the build work on the command line?

Comment: Command line build works! Seems to be an IDE error. I'm using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)

Comment: Try upating your project.    `Right Click on your project ->  Maven -> Update Project`

Comment: Maven Updating does not help. The Maven Dependencies listing in the project explorer is updated accordingly when I change the version.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this error with the same IDE?

Comment: please add `pom.xml` to the question

Answer (score 0):

There is not any issue in Spring -4.3.5 regarding @Controller annotation

Add the following into your POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```